# Tangent plane of an implicit system of equations

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, implicit-function-theorem

The next system of equations implicitly define to the equations $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$

$$xe^{2u+3v}-2uv=1$$
$$ye^{u-v}-\frac{u+1}{v+1}=2x$$

Find the tangent plane equation to the graphic of the function $u(x,y)$ in the point where $x=1,y=2,u=v=0$.

I've been trying to do this exercise but I still do not understand how to use the system of equations to calculate that. I appreciate some explanation of how to answer this.

If someone has some example or reference about the tangent plane of an implicit system of equations. It would be a great help.

I made this,
firsts that all, I wanted to calculate $u_x$ and $u_y)$.

1. I define $F_1(x,y,u(x,y),v(x,y))$ and $F_2(x,y,u(x,y),v(x,y))$ as.

$$F_1(x,y,u(x,y),v(x,y))=xe^{2u+3v}-2uv-1$$
$$F_2(x,y,u(x,y),v(x,y))=ye^{u-v}-\frac{u+1}{v+1}-2x$$

2. Now I calculated $\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x}$,$\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y}$,$\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u}$,$\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial v}$, $\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y}$, $\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial v}$.

what I get was

$\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x}=e^{2u+3v}$,
$\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y}=0$,
$\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u}=e^{2u+3v}-2-2v$,
$\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial v}=3e^{2u+3v}-2u$,
$\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x}=-2$,
$\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y}=e^{u-v}$,
$\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u}=ye^{u-v}-\frac{1}{v+1}$,
$\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial v}=ye^{u-v}+\frac{u+1}{(v+1)^2}$.

3. I evaluated this in the point (1,2,0,0) and answered the following system of equations
   $$\begin{bmatrix}-1&3\\1&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u_x\\v_x\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\2\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$\begin{bmatrix}-1&3\\1&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u_x\\v_x\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

so I get $u_x=3/2,u_y=1/4$ and $v_x=1/6,v_y=1/4$

So I think that the tangent plane of $u(x,y)$ is (2/3)(x-1)+(1/4)(y-2)=0.

So far I have been able to resolve this, I would like to know if I am on the right track or should I follow another procedure.

Comment: Hi, I do not want someone to answer the exercise, In the text, it just appears how to calculate the tangent plane of an implicit function, but it doesn't show anything about the system of equations I've been searching for examples of tangent planes for a system of implicit equations but I could not find anything about it, I really appreciate some example or document where I can understand how to answer this kind of questions, It would be a great help. thanks.

Comment: Writing some of that *context* you just provided me, in an edit to your post would greatly improve your question, and help answerers better hone in on what you need.  I also added the tag "reference request".  Thanks for interacting; best to respond to suggestions by editing one's post!  Cheers!

Comment: "tangent plane equation to the graphic of the function..." Is it $u(x,v)$ or $u(x,y)$?

Comment: sorry it was $u(x,y)$ I just corrected it, thanks.

Comment: You can begin with finding the partial derivatives $u_x$ and $u_y$. The PDE tag is not quite relevant here.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @jhoan !

Comment: I added to the question what I made until now, I hope that I am following an adequate procedure, I would appreciate it if you could tell me if I am on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You could have used `@user` to ping me.

Comment: See also: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/TangentPlanes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Once you find $u_x(x_0,y_0)$ and $u_y(x_0,y_0)$, the tangent plane should be
$$z=u(x_0,y_0)+u_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+u_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$$

Comment: ok I finded $u_x(x_0,y_0)$ and $u_y(x_0,y_0)$, but how I get $u(x_0,y_0)$